# Doxygen not generating doc for global functions

Tags: c, doxygen, documentation-generation

I have a C header file with lots of methods being declared, all of them contain valid doxygen tags to generate documentation, however doxygen fails to create any documentation for the methods, unless I set the `EXTRACT_ALL` to be true, but even in this case, the methods appear just in the documentation of the header file... I would like to have a collection point "Functions" that will have a list of methods, where I can click on them ... Is this possible? (my output is optimized to C/PHP however setting it to something else does not help at all)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You MUST documented the file if you want to generate documents for global functions. This is an example:

```c
/**
 * @file buffer.h
 *
 * Interfaces to Data Buffer.
 *
 * This header define the interfaces of general purpose dynamic data buffer that
 * implemented by Equinox.
 */
#ifndef _EQUINOX_BUFFER_H
#define _EQUINOX_BUFFER_H
```

Comment: better to leave the name of the file out.  If the file name is left out the name of the file is assumed. It also avoids the need to update the name if the header file's name is changed.